# Spring Boot 2 Security downloading font file upon login

Tags: spring-boot

I've setup a spring boot 2 application with a login form, however, when you login, instead of redirecting to `/admin` like it's supposed to, it downloads a font file referenced by the stylesheet via an @import.

Here is my security setup;

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity()
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();

        // These pages don't require the user to be logged in
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login", "/logout", "/report/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        // When the user has logged in as XX.
        // But access a page that requires role YY,
        // AccessDeniedException will be thrown.
        http.authorizeRequests().and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");

        // Config for Login Form
        http.authorizeRequests().and().formLogin()//
                // Submit URL of login page.
                .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check") // Submit URL
                .loginPage("/login")//
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin")//
                .failureUrl("/login?error=true")//
                .usernameParameter("username")//
                .passwordParameter("password")
                // Config for Logout Page
                .and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout=true");
    }
}
```

Where am I going wrong? From what I can see, I'm enabling access to Spring resources that are stored in the `static` folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this one out, I read the code that allows access to resources and noticed it said 'atCommonLocations', and guess this adds access to folders such as css, js, img, images etc. I had fonts in a folder labelled `webfonts`, so I updated my security configuration;

```
http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login", "/logout", "/report/**", "/webfonts/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
```